# Problems trying to build flutter app for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I'm working on a project that I'm trying to build on Xcode's iOS simulator and the build keeps failing because of a whole load of errors that I don't really understand.

Looking for guidance and help if anyone has the time.

Thanks

````
Xcode build done.                                           11.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/chris/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/screenshot_callback-1.1.1/ios/Classes/SwiftScreenshotCallbackPlugin.swift:27:34: error: 'userDidTakeScreenshotNotification' has been renamed to 'NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot'
              forName: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification,
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot
    UIKit.UIApplication:73:22: note: 'userDidTakeScreenshotNotification' was introduced in Swift 4.2
        public class let userDidTakeScreenshotNotification: NSNotification.Name
                         ^
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'camera' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'camera' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
Exited (sigterm)```
````

Answer (score 2):

Try this command in your project's ios / folder

```
pod install
```

If already installed, use

```
pod update
```

If you are using any camera plugin or image_picker let me know

Comment: I did pod install and got 2 alerts... one saying "Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `11.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified." and another saying "CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configu......."

Comment: Okay, this is in my projects too.

Are you building via workspace or proj?